# Unity con mysql

Tags: php, mysql, unity3d, unity

Tengo problemas con **Unity** y con **mysql**, al tratar de mandara  traer la tabla única que tengo en una base de datos en el servidor de Square7, y lo que me muestra al llamar lo que tiene la tabla es lo que ven en la imagen. :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este es el código php**

```
<?php
m_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$enlace=mysqli_connect("localhost","cristian","xxxxxxxx","cristian_players");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    printf("Conexion Fallida: %s\n",mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

mysqli_set_charset($enlace,"utf-8");
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM `Puntajes` ORDER by `puntuacion` DESC LIMIT 10";
$resultado=mysqli_query($enlace,$consulta);

$num = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo  $row[`Nombre`]. ";" . $row[`puntuacion`]. ";";

}

?>
```

**Y este es el código UNITY**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class verJugadores : MonoBehaviour {

    private string URLVerPuntuacion = "cristian.square7.ch/RankingScripts/VerPuntuacion.php";
    private List<Jugador> RankingJugadores = new List<Jugador>();
    private string[] CurrentArray = null;
    public Transform tfPanelCargarDatos;
    public Text txtCargandoDatos;
    public GameObject PanelPre;

    void Start() {
        StartCoroutine(ObtenerJugadores());
    }

    IEnumerator ObtenerJugadores() {
        txtCargandoDatos.text = "Cargando...";
        WWW DataServer = new WWW("http://"+URLVerPuntuacion);
        yield return DataServer;
        if (DataServer.error != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Problemas al intentar obtener los jugadores de la base de datos: " + DataServer.error);
            txtCargandoDatos.text = DataServer.error;
        }
        else {

            txtCargandoDatos.text = "";
            ObtenerRegistros(DataServer);
            VerRegistros();

        }
    }

    void ObtenerRegistros(WWW DataServer) {
        CurrentArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(DataServer.bytes).Split(";"[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i <= CurrentArray.Length - 3; i = i + 2) {
            RankingJugadores.Add(new Jugador(CurrentArray[i],CurrentArray[i+1]));
        }
    }

    void VerRegistros() {
        for (int i = 0; i < RankingJugadores.Count; i++) {
            GameObject obj = Instantiate(PanelPre);
            Jugador jg = RankingJugadores[i];
            obj.GetComponent<setScore>().SetScore(jg.Nombre, jg.puntuacion);
            obj.transform.SetParent(tfPanelCargarDatos);
            obj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        }
    }

}

public class Jugador
{
    public string puntuacion;
    public string Nombre;

    public Jugador(string nombreJugador, string puntuacionJugador) {
        puntuacion = puntuacionJugador;
        Nombre = nombreJugador;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a llamar a la URL desde un navegador? Mira el log de acceso y error de tu servidor web, es probable que estés accediendo a la URL incorrecta y eso que ves es parte de la página de `404 Not found` (página no encontrada) o bien te esté saliendo algún tipo de advertencia o error en tu código.

Comment: Intenta imprimir en consola lo que regresa de esa petición, ya que lo que muestras probablemente sea el inicio de una pagina 404 de tu servicio en la nube. Al ser una petición GET es fácil verificar que esto funcione en el navegador.